# Permanent redirect in Orchard CMS (1.5)

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, orchardcms

I recreated an old website using Orchard CMS but there is a bunch of legacy links in various search engines that I want to redirect to their Orchard counterparts. I know I need to modify web.config but I am not sure how.

EDIT:
Found this site http://iis7-rewrite.heroku.com/ that does 301 rewrites for web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general ASP.Net topic, not an Orchard-specific one. Depending on your server, you can use different way to do it. If you are using IIS 7 and above, then the task is easier as you can do it in web.config. Search IIS 7 URL Rewrite for more information, or try this as a starter http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use web.config, in which case what you need to read is the IIS documentation on the subject, or you can use the Rewrite Rules module.

Comment: I installed rewrite rules module. Can you give me a simple example of what I need to enter there. E.g. I want to redirect mysite.com/contactus.html to mysite.com/contact. i don't need to use any wild cards, I have only a couple of pages that i can redirect manually one by one. Thanks